# Antlr C# не могу установить

Tags: c#, antlr

В интернете посмотрел много статей, нет подходящих, в них всё начинается с установки Antlr Language support через nuget но там его нет! Подскажите кто сталкивался.

Comment: Есть? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr/ . Language support  это расширение для студии судя по гуглу https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.ANTLRLanguageSupport

Comment: да для студии только вот её нет

Comment: Почему нет то, я же кинул ссылку. Нугеты и расширения это разные вещи.